# Is the Immersed Boundary (IB) method a Direct Numerical Simulation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulation, terminology

Is the **Immersed Boundary (IB)** method considered a **Direct Numerical Simulation**?

A DNS code is the most detailed type of simulation and the most accurate but computationally expensive, right?

What makes a simulation **not** a DNS?

Answer (score 1):

The term immersed boundary method has nothing to do with the term direct numerical simulation.

The **immersed boundary method** is a numerical methodology that is often used to handle heterogeneous fluid regions in your simulation domain.

For example:

- Fluid-structure interaction
- Multi-phase flows

The term **direct numerical simulation** is often used in the LES community where the underlying equation system, e.g. Navier-Stokes, is numerically solved without any turbulence model. This means that the whole range of spatial and temporal scales of the turbulence must be resolved.
The term can also be understood more generally as a highly resolved numerical simulation of a given PDE without additional modelling where all relevant physical effects are sufficiently accurately resolved.

Comment: your last sentence potentially conflicts with your first one

Comment: @Spencer Bryngelson There are a few sentences. Could you be more precise?

Comment: How would you answer this question?

Comment: if the IBM models unresolved physics then it subject to your last sentence. depending on what one considers “unresolved” and “physics” then it may well be classified and “yes, DNS” or “no, not DNS”, depending on your interpretation of the aforementioned terms. I believe this is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Spencer Bryngelson I don't say that the immersed boundary method isn't able to reproduce a DNS or not. I mentioned that the IBM is a numerical methodology, whereas the DNS is not.

Comment: There's a potential category error going on here, I agree, though your last sentence blurs the categories in question. For example, if I model and simulated a flow-coupled combustion problem, what degree of modeling is considered "additional" and what physics are "relevant"? There is no unique definition here. If you interpret DNS strictly as grid resolution down to sub-Kolmogorov scales, then this question makes no sense. If you broaden your view (as one might, per your last sentence), then it becomes more complicated.

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson I think we should agree that the question about IBM and DNS is a category error. This is the main issue of my answer. How DNS is defined in different communities is something I didn't want to explain in detail here. There are probably dozens of opinions on this.

Comment: @Jessica In the context you are thinking, any numerical method that can resolve turbulent scales (spectral methods, compact finite differences, etc.) can be used for DNS. IBM is not a numerical method of the same sort, and so it does not fit this description. However, be aware that (as ConvexHull mentioned) DNS is a term that has been abused in some sense, and people might use it in other ways (per my earlier comment).

Comment: My take for brevity: IB is a way of dealing with boundary conditions. DNS is a way of dealing with the equation in the domain circumscribed by the boundaries.